# Kafka Cluster Authorization Failed error after updating spring-boot-starter-parent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a spring-boot application that is configured as a Kafka producer & consumer. previously it was running the following POM dependencies

```xml
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot></groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aprent</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath />
</parent>
<properties>
  <spring-framwork.version>5.2.20.RELEASE</spring-framwork.version>
  <spring-cloud.version>HOXTON.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
.......
```

with the above, everything was working as expected, but after updating the above POM to the below

```xml
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot></groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aprent</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.14</version>
  <relativePath />
</parent>
<properties>
  <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
  ....
</properties>
<dependencies>
  .......
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  .......
</dependencies>
```

Now I'm getting the producer throwing a cluster authorization error, even though nothing has changed from the kafka configuration / certs department.

> org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Cluster authorization failed.
> at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.lambda$buildCallback$6(KafkaTemplate.java:696)
> at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer$1.onCompletion(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:1095)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer$InterceptorCallback.onCompletion(KafkaProducer.java:1350)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.completeFutureAndFireCallbacks(ProducerBatch.java:273)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.abort(ProducerBatch.java:161)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.abortBatches(RecordAccumulator.java:773)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.maybeAbortBatches(Sender.java:498)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:307)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:243)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Cluster authorization failed.

I'm not sure exactly why would that happen, all the authentications & certs haven't changed... I'm letting spring manage the Kafka versions so there are no version conflicts.

any thoughts or help are very much appreciated.

Comment: All connection/auth activity is delegated to the `kafka-clients`; the version will have changed (note that even Boot 2.6.x is no longer supported as OSS - https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support ). However, nothing has changed in Spring that would affect authorization. I suggest you look at the server logs.